# Convert region between ellipses to bezier path

Tags: inkscape

In an Inkscape file I got from somebody I found the following:
[image]

On the right there are arcs of ellipses (not paths), and on the left there are 4-node bezier paths each perfectly corresponding to the inside of the set of four ellipses next to it.
I have been trying to do the same: I create four arcs of ellipses and try to convert the inside region to a single path. Given the above examples I guess there must be a very quick way to do it, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in the following steps:

1. Make full ellipses (e.g. 3 ellipses)
2. Take the complement for the green and red ellipses (Ctrl -). It will automatically produce a path.
3. Break apart the result and delete the bottom part if you don't need it (Ctrl Shift K).
4. Take the union (Ctrl *)

[image]

Comment: A bit tedious, but it's the only option I can imagine. Sometimes it's hard to think of which boolean operations should be used, but I guess I will be able to handle all cases this way.

Answer (score 1):

A very fast method to get an object of an inner area of several overlapping objects is the bucket fill tool.[image].

This is how it works:

1. Draw overlapping objects:

   [image]
2. Apply *Bucket Fill*:

   [image]
3. Move new object from bucket-fill or apply custom stroke and fill:

   [image] [image]

Comment: I was aware of the bucket fill (I should have mentioned it) but unfortunately this does not fill the shape perfectly. I guess the solution with boolean path operations is the best. +1 though for the effort, I'm happy to see an active community on this SE site.